# sync Exchange public contacts folder with mobile devices

Tags: exchange, mobile-phone, activesync

Is there a way to sync a public contacts folder from exchange to iphone/android
(without a 3rd party ?)
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can download one simple app name is Shareit. it will help you to transfer all your data from android to iPhone, android to android, iPhone to android, PC to Android, PC to iPhone everything is possible through this app.For the installation and setup details you can go to the following link which I found on one blog.

https://feelsecured.wordpress.com/2015/03/05/how-to-transfer-contacts-music-pictures-videos-from-android-to-iphone/